# Why am does saving text files to database result in duplicates?

Tags: c#

this is the data inside the text file i have.

```
[Start]
"Pepsi"|"30"|"64"
"Coke"|"35"|"24"
"Sandwich"|"60"|"14"
"Chicken"|"120"|"10"
"Bread"|"60"|"24"
[End]
```

[image]

```
var files = from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\Users\K\Desktop\New folder", "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            from line in File.ReadLines(file)
            select new
            {
                File = file,
                Line = line
            };
using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(@"server=localhost;database=test;uid=root;pwd=pw;"))
{
 con.Open();
 foreach (var f in files)
    {
    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", f.File, f.Line);
    string[] Lines = File.ReadAllLines(f.File);
    bool processRecord = false;

        foreach (string line in Lines)
        {
            if (!processRecord)
            {
                if (Lines.Contains("[Start]"))
                {
                    processRecord = true;
                    continue;
                }
                if (Lines.Contains("[End]"))
                {
                    processRecord = false;
                    continue;
                }
            }

            if (processRecord)
            {
                string[] readLineSplit = line.Split('|');

                if (readLineSplit.Length > 1)
                {
                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO Products(Product_Name, Product_Price, QTY) VALUES (@Product_Name, @Product_Price, @QTY)", con);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Product_Name", readLineSplit[0].Trim('\"'));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Product_Price", readLineSplit[1].Trim('\"'));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QTY", readLineSplit[2].Trim('\"'));
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
      }
  }
```

this is the code i have so far, i have no idea which part of the code is causing the multiple records, what is the problem? i need any help i can get, thanks.

Comment: yes, i even drop the table then re run the program.

Comment: _[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)_,

Comment: I have reworded your title to be a _question_ rather than a _observation_.  Welcome to SO by the way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var files = from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\Users\K\Desktop\New folder", "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                            from line in File.ReadLines(file)
                            select new
                            {
                                File = file,
                                Line = line
                            };
```

This is producing an entry for each line in the file. Like:

```
foo.txt | text here,text here, text here.
foo.txt | text here, text here, text here. 
etc..
```

Then you loop over these and for each line you process the whole file again by reading all of it's lines. And that of course will lead to duplication. Try changing the first line to

```
 var files = from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\Users\K\Desktop\New folder", "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories) select new { File = file };
```

Comment: i tried this and still getting duplicates 

`code` var files = from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\Users\Kevin\Desktop\New folder", "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                             from line in File.ReadLines(file)
                             select new 
                            { File = file };`code`

Comment: remove the "from line in File.Readlines(file)" part.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you read all lines of all files again in the loop? You have already read them into `files`.  So the inner loop is redundant.

Instead of ...

```
foreach (var f in files)
{
    string[] Lines = File.ReadAllLines(f.File);
    bool processRecord = false;
    foreach (string line in Lines)
    {  ....
```

you have the line in the anonymous type:

```
foreach (var f in files)
{
    string line = f.Line;
    // ...
```

Can this cause your duplicates?

Comment: i removed string[] Lines = File.ReadAllLines(f.File); and replaced it with string Lines = f.Line; then im getting cannot convert type char to string on foreach (string line in Lines)

Comment: @KevinRodriguez: as i've said, you don't need the  inner loop since you have already the (single) line.